# How do i get a reference to all managed threads

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I know there's nothing in the box ... but does anyone have any tricks.

Managed threads not OS threads please.

Cheers

Answering the comments:

Version is .Net 3.5.

I want all managed threads in the current running process.

I want them so I can get the call stack of everythread.

Thanks

Comment: In your process? In all processes? What .NET Version?

Comment: Waht are you going to do with them when you get them?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that anything at this level would be done with the debugging hooks outside of managed code. By design, it isn't really geared up to let you do that. Of course, you could just use any existing debugger, etc (even just windbg/sos).

For you *own* threads - simply store away a reference when you create them. But of course, don't do this as a mechanism to abort them etc - there are much better (i.e. workable) ways of doing that with things like `Monitor`, `Mutex`, etc.

Of course, if you don't mind stepping outside of managed code I'm sure there are options...